# Rules for Symbol.toPrimitive argument

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```js
function Answer() {
  this[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(hint) {
    console.log('convert to ' + hint);
    if (hint == 'string') {
      return 'the answer is 42';
    } else if (hint == 'number') {
      return 42;
    } else {
      return "default";
    }
  }
}
var a = new Answer();
console.log(10 + a);
console.log(+a);
console.log(''+a);
console.log(`${a}`)
```

```
+object
```

the Symbol.toPrimitive is called with "number" but when I call:

`10+object` or `''+object`

It's called with "default" in Chrome

Where can I find rules to the hint argument? on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) there'are links to [specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-symbol.toprimitive) but they include only two sentence.

Comment: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive

Comment: @Teemu thanks, I thought it's only that one section in link.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this, @jcubic?

Comment: @oligofren no, maybe you will need to send an email to W3C or some working group. Maybe a good idea is to find someone that is in a working group and reach to him on Twitter.